# How to escape '|' in SQL Server or T-SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM performance_table
WHERE ad_group like '%|%'
```

I have no idea on how to escape the Pipe operator here.

Comment: Why are you trying to escape `|`? it is not considered a wildcard character in a `like` statement, only `_` and `%` is.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to escape `|` in T-SQL as it has no special meaning inside `like`. However, if for example you would like to find texts containing % character, what you're looking for is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM performance_table
WHERE ad_group like '%#%%' escape '#'
```

where `escape` defines escape character.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe character does not need to be escaped.
Your query will find all records that contain a pipe character in the ad_group column.

When used inside a string literal ('|'), the character is not treated as an operator. Its function as an operator is [bitwise OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql), as for example in

```
select 8|3
```

will be 11.